# How to make Lisp state a default instead of normal?

Tags: spacemacs, evil, clojure

I'm learning Clojure and Emacs at the same time  I use Spacemacs with Evil.

Recently I've learned about `Lisp state` and I find it very handy. The only problem is that whenever I switch to `insert state` to type some code and then leave it, I end up in `normal state` and have to go back to `Lisp state` with `SPC k .`, which is quite a streak. In Clojure (including Cider REPL) I find `Lisp state` superior to `normal`, so I would like to have it like that:

- When entering Clojure buffer start in the `Lisp state`
- When leaving `insert` / `visual` / etc., e.g. by pressing `ESC` - go to Lisp state
- When pressing `ESC` in `Lisp state` - go to the `normal state`
- When pressing `ESC` id `normal state` - go to `Lisp state`

So basically, in Clojure mode, I want to make `Lisp state` a default, just like `normal` is right now, with additional feature of having `ESC` switch between the two.

Does it make sense? Is it possible? I bet it is :) How?

Comment: sounds interesting. I never used it, I have emacs-state as default with : `(setq evil-default-state 'emacs)` . also look at the bottom of the github page: https://github.com/syl20bnr/evil-lisp-state